# Missing required dependencies ['numpy'] for anaconda ver5.3.1 on pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, anaconda, conda

I just installed anaconda ver5.3.1 which uses python 3.7.

I encountered the following error;

> "Missing required dependencies {0}".format(missing_dependencies))
>    ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']

I have upgraded `numpy`, pandas to the latest version using `conda` but the same error appears. To fix this problem, I have to downgrade to an older anaconda version which uses python 3.6

I am using Windows 10.

EDIT: I just discovered this problem is more related to pycharm than anaconda. I got this error while running pycharm in debug mode. However, when I run the same python script in Anaconda prompt console, there is no error.

What are some possible pycharm settings I should check to fix this problem? Are there ways to configure pycharm to output more verbose error messages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a known issue in PyCharm https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-32366

For a workaround you can define the correct `PATH` in a run configuration in PyCharm (get the value by activating the conda env in the terminal and `echo %PATH%`).

Comment: I guess the simplest solution is to wait for a new update of pycharm to fix this problem. For the time being, stick with python v3.6.

Answer (score 1):

Your pycharm created a new environment for your project I suspect. Maybe it copied across the anaconda python.exe but not all the global packages.

In pycharm you can go to the project properties where you can see a list of all the packages available, and add additional packages. Here you can install Numpy.

File --> Settings --> Project:  --> Project Interpreter